# Questions related to efficient DML in procedure/functions

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, dml

I have 2 questions regarding performance of PL/SQL script when executing DML. Ofcourse the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is the slowest one thats why we have `forall`, `bulk` insert etc. My Questions are

1. I have to manipulate data in 3 different tables. `Table1` (insert data), `Table2`(update data) and `Table3` delete data. All of these would be done based on the values fetched using a cursor. the question is what would be more efficient here?

   - Putting each of these statements in individual `Forall` block? i.e.

> ```
> fetch cursor
> loop
>    forall loop for table 1
>    forall loop for table 2
>    forall loop for table 3
> end loop
> ```

OR

- a global loop and execute these statments in that loop i.e.

> ```
> fetch cursor loop
>     for i IN array.count 
>     loop
>        3 statements for DML
>     end loop end loop
> ```

Now my second question

1. what is the efficient way to delete records in loop? I fetched the values of the records to be deleted through the cursor. now what would be the efficient way to delete them?

P.S:
Execuse my formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient approach would be to write three SQL statements, assuming the data fetched from the cursor is stable over the period of time that the procedure is running

```
INSERT INTO table1( list_of_columns )
  <<your SELECT statement>>

UPDATE table2
   SET (<<list of columns>>) = (<<your SELECT statement joined to table2>>)
 WHERE EXISTS( <<your SELECT statement joined to table2>> );

DELETE FROM table3
 WHERE EXISTS( <<your SELECT statement joined to table3>> );
```

If the `SELECT` statement will potentially return different results in each of the three DML statements, then it makes sense to accept the performance hit of using a cursor, bulk collecting the data into PL/SQL collections, and looping over the collections in order to ensure consistent results.  If that's what you're doing, it will be more efficient to have three `FORALL` statements since that involves fewer context shifts between the SQL and PL/SQL engines.

> What is the efficient way to delete records in loop? I fetched the values of the records to be deleted through the cursor. now what would be the efficient way to delete them?

I'm not sure I understand the question.  Wouldn't you just do a `FORALL` loop just as you would for an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`

```
FORALL i IN l_array.first .. l_array.last
  DELETE FROM some_table
   WHERE some_key = l_array(i);
```

Or are you asking a different question?

Comment: It is helpful. Regarding `FORALL` i believe *ORACLE10G* doesn't have `bulk`/`bind` options. It gave error. So far oracle 10 g I was forced to choose `FOR` loop. Regarding `Deleting` a record. Would it be efficient to fetch `ROWID` to delete the record or using the `key` comparison would be better?

Comment: @x.509 - Oracle 10g certainly supports a `FORALL` with a `DELETE` along with bulk binds.  If you're getting an error, can you edit your question to post the code you're using and the error you're getting.  Using a `ROWID` may be marginally faster than using a key on the `DELETE` but you may lose that time on the `SELECT` since, presumably, you need the key and not the `ROWID` for the `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

Comment: Justine, I had an error `forall` but i figured it out. http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=410 ... right now i was concerned about performance.